# Problem with creating a docker container with postgres - result differs on Windows and Mac

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump

I am using a MacBook in my development environment and for me this process is working. I have a couple of interns that are sitting on Windows and we cannot get this to work for them.

We have a [script](https://gist.github.com/tobiasgardner/150ffa1dd0cfec6f8e4124744e513752) that uses pg_dump to dump our development database (hosted on digital ocean) to a file: schema.sql
That schema.sql is used when creating a docker container for local use (development and testing).
Our docker-compose.yml looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/tobiasgardner/4f90bd65744b882de37d2b38cc73db6f).

When I run the script on my local machine (MacBook), after the database has been dumped, it starts to create the database with the content in the schema.sql:
And the database comes up as it should...

But when my interns run the same script, on Windows / VS Code / bash, they get this error:

```
ERROR: role "postgres" does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER to postgres;
```

Note! When we look in the file schema.sql, we cannot find that statement in there...
Workaround, that seems to do it, is to add the following line at the top of the schema.sql file:

```
CREATE ROLE postgres WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Questions...

1. Why is this needed in their environment (Windows) and not on my environment (Mac)?
2. Is there a better way to do this than adding the CREATE ROLE statement to the schema.sql file?

Things that might (?) have an impact:

- Database that is exported is Postgres 11
- I am running pg_dump for v14
- My interns are running pg_dump for v15
- The local database (docker container) is v15